# Ajax gets nested data, the result 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, serialization

I have simple ajax call

```
$.get("api/dashboard/tile/1x1/" + tag, { id: id },
               function (tile) {
                   options.result(modelmapper.fromDb(tile, 'dashboard'));
               }, 'json')
```

Which reads from ASP.NET MVC controller. Object Tile nested into Person

```
class Person{
public int Id { get; set; }
public Tile Tile { get; set; }}

class Tile{
public int Id { get; set; }}
```

Problem: When Id's are different than everything works fine, bit if Id are the same then

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

The only one solution I can see (and obviously it works) to rename Id to something meaningful like PersonId, but then I'm loosing a lot of flexibility and need to re-write significant part of app. Please help.

UPDATE
Controller

```
[System.Web.Http.ActionName("tile")]
    [System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("GET")]
    // GET api/dashboard/tile/1x1/person
    public Person Tile()
    {
        var tile = new Tile();
        tile.Id = 1;

        var personTile = new Person();
        personTile.Id = 1;
        personTile.Tile = tile;
        return personTile;
    }
```

SOLUTION: The only one solution I found if forcibly serialize data in controller  JsonConvert.SerializeObject  and then desalinize on client side JSON.Parse()

Comment: show us your controller code

Comment: 500 server error indicates that you have a failure in your server side code. You'll need to do whatever is necessary to fix that before you can rely on your AJAX code.

Comment: but I'm able to receive XML when call it from address bar

Comment: it could be serialization kind of problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only one solution I found if forcibly serialize data in controller JsonConvert.SerializeObject and then desalinize on client side JSON.Parse()